# S3 lambda upload issue: Broken pipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Program works well in debug, but failed upload into AWS lambda, issue with version 2.15.20, we got the below details exceptions in S3 cloudWatch:

```
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   2020-12-28T05:25:59.108Z [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Retryable error detected. Will retry in 66ms. Request attempt number 3
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Broken pipe (Write failed)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:43)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:205)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:66)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:34)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
2020-12-28T13:25:59.109+08:00   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
```

Comment: please provide a better explanation and a code example of how exactly you reached this point

Comment: PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).metadata(meta)
    .key(fileDir + "/" + s3ObjectKey).contentLength(new Long(file.length).longValue()).contentDisposition(fileName).build();
  PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = s3Client.putObject(request, RequestBody.fromBytes(file));

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this - Lambdas have a maximum request and response length of 6Mb, and a mistake in my code was returning a lot more than this. Reducing down the size fixed the issue for me.